# Who is Ratman in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the story behind the drawings on the wall in Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20821/whats-the-story-behind-the-drawings-on-the-wall-in-portal-2)

I've been playing portal 2 and sometimes I see a bunch of "secret" places, and weird music starts playing when I get in them. I went on the net and searched about what it is, and it said that there was a dude called **Ratman** that was there before Chell.

I just wanted to find out who he is and what was his goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ratman is the protagonist of the [Lab Rat](http://www.thinkwithportals.com/comic) Portal 2 comic and one of the scientists that worked to the GladOS project, probably the only survivor. He managed to escape the killer AI for a long time thanks to his paranoia.

The secret places you find are his hideouts, the places where GladOS couldn't see, and therefore "safe".

As you can see in the comic, he's been the only living witness of the first defeat of GladOS by the hands of Chell. He's working behind the curtains to help Chell defeat GladOS once and for all, by putting her as the first testing subject. As it is shown in the last page, Chell has an abnormal tenacity level, that makes more likely her survival through the ordeal of the test chambers.

So, basically, Ratman is the real hero behind Chell's victory.